# Array of anonymous functions working in julia 0.4, not in 0.5.1

Tags: arrays, julia, anonymous-function

I'm porting some code from Julia 0.4.7 to 0.5.1. I've noticed that there is something not compatible related to the array of anonymous functions. The code is here:

```
f = x::Array{Function} -> size(x)

# Option 1    
f([k -> k+1, k-> k+1]) # This works in 0.4 & 0.5

# Option 2
f(repmat([k -> k+1], 2)) # This only works in 0.4
```

As far as I can see, the difference is although in 0.4 the anonymous array is still internally seen as Array{Function, 1}, in 0.5 it's seen like Array{#11#12, 1} (the numbers may change), so then it raises a MethodError thus they don't match.

Although the example is stupid it shows what I really need: to replicate an anonymous function a variable number of times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Julia 0.5+, [`Function` becomes an abstract type](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#language-changes-1), so `Array{Function}` is a parametric type which is *invariant*.

```
julia> typeof(x -> 2x) 
##1#2

julia> typeof(x -> 2x) <: Function
true

julia> typeof([x -> 2x]) <: Array{Function}
false
```

As a result, the correct way to define `f` is:

```
f{T<:Function}(x::Array{T}) = size(x)

julia> f(repmat([k -> k+1], 2))
(2,)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After your explanation, a workaround comes to my mind, which is converting the array: `code` f(Array{Function}(repmat([k -> k+1], 2))) `code`